# assign a javascript variable value depends on html drop down list section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop html list. If I select an option from dropdown, I have to assign dropdown value to the  javascript variable and display it on html

Here is my code

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" onchange="changeHiddenInput(this)">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>

    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenInput" id="hiddenInput" value="" />

    <button onclick="changeHiddenInput (objDropDown)">Try it</button>
</form>
<div id="result"> </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function changeHiddenInput (objDropDown)
{
    var objHidden = document.getElementById("hiddenInput");
    objHidden.value = objDropDown.value; 
    var a = objHidden.value;
     result.innerHTML = a || "";
}
```

But whenever I am submitting the values,it giving error. anything wrong here ?

**[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/aY3Em/)**

Comment: I made a last update, it might be usefull for you. Please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your demo, you've selected the default onLoad option in jsfiddle.
This causes the site to wrap your entire code within a callback function, meaning that your showit function is not a global function as required by DOM0 inline event handlers.

Change this option to no wrap(head) and it will work.

The code you have will work good on a page, assuming you have the `<script>` tags for the javascript.

[**Fiddle here**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Zhc2V/)

About your `<button onclick="changeHiddenInput (objDropDown)">Try it</button>`, `objDropDown` is not defined... and also add `type="button"` otherwise the default is a submit button.

I made some changes for the demo, so my code is:

html

```
<form method="post">
    <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" onchange="changeHiddenInput(this)">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>

    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenInput" id="hiddenInput" value="" />

    <button onclick="changeHiddenInput (objDropDown)">Try it</button>
</form>

<div id="result"> </div>
```

javascript

```
var select;
window.onload = function () {
    select = document.getElementById('dropdown');
    console.log(select);
}

function changeHiddenInput(objDropDown) {
    console.log(objDropDown);
    var objHidden = document.getElementById("hiddenInput");
    objHidden.value = objDropDown.value;
    var a = objHidden.value;
    result.innerHTML = a || "";
}
```

Comment: Since I am using form post method, will i able to pass the variable value to php echo ?

Comment: @acr, all inputs with name, including hidden inouts, will be passed to php, since you use `post` you can get them by `$_POST['dropdown']` and `$_POST['hiddenInput']`